# Get the file text into a variable in C

Tags: c, file, variables

I am doing a game and I want to do a highscore save with a file.

I have a highscore.txt that has written in it '55'

I want to get that 55 number into a variable. Can you guys help me.

I only can put one int in my variable with my code and don't know how to do a loop as I use ints and chars :

```
char c;
c = fgetc(fichier) - '0';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your issues fscanf/fprintf will be more sufficient
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int score;
    FILE* f = fopen("highscore.txt", "r");
    fscanf(f, "%d", &score);
    return 0;
}
```